# VBA UserForms noModal and Modal interaction problem

Tags: excel, vba, modal-dialog, userform

I have a UserForm1, which works as a menu allowing to start different actions, some on the worksheets and sometimes on other forms.
The userForm1 is NOT MODAL. The UserForm2 is MODAL.
When calling an instance of userForm2 from userForm1, it executes correctly, but when the proc of the usrForm1 call ends, it closes usrForm1.

UserForm1 Code

```
'SET USERFORM1 PROPERTY SHOWMODAL = FALSE

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim f As UserForm2
    Set f = New UserForm2
    f.Show
    Set f = Nothing
End Sub
```

UserForm2 Code

```
'SET USERFORM2 PROPERTY SHOWMODAL = TRUE

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Hide
End Sub
```

When executing the button event on UserForm1, the instance of UserForm2 is displayed in modal form. When the control returns to the button event on UserForm1, it deletes the instance of UserForm2, but upon completion it closes UserForm1 TOO ...

Any ideas?

Comment: `Set f = Nothing` is redundant because the object is going out of scope on the next line, but it could be useful to include the code that's showing userform1. Does userform1 have any other code?

Comment: ok  thanks,  it was a good idea.  I just was testing from debbuger, but creating the instance of UserForm1 from Workbook_Open it works fine.